# How to properly save string with quotation marks to database for further displaying?

Tags: php, html, database, forms, security

I want save some form data on database.
The form:

```
echo '<form action="post" method="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name']).' />
<input type="text" name="last_name" value="htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name']).' />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>';
```

If some input is empty it do refresh to same page and show error at top that say to fill the inputs.

The problem is when I fill only one input to value aaa"aaa and the another save empty, than I submit. Than I get error that say to fill the another input and the filled value change from aaa"aaa to aaa&quot;aaa.

Because of that when I save the data on database some of the data is escaped and some data is not.

I thought to use htmlspecialchars_decode but if I will type aaa&quot;aaa it will convert it to aaa"aaa when i want save it as it is (aaa&quot;aaa).

What I can do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest you to use Javascript Validation to check every field and then if it's everything ok then let it be saved in database.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestov But you cant validate everything at javascript, for example, gd picture. Must be way to solve it in side client, I just cant found it!

Comment: what do you mean by good picture? You can validate everything in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do verification of user data, certainly you need to do it on front-end (javascript) and in back-end (for security reasons).

Anyway, first of all I see mistakes in your php code. There is no some proper concatenation symbols and quotation marks. Correct piece of code should be:

```
echo '<form action="post" method="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name']).'" />
<input type="text" name="last_name" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name']).'" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>';
```

If you really want to display quotaion marks, which were been inserted by your users, as variant you can use `html_entity_decode($your_variable_here);`

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";
$a = htmlspecialchars($orig);
$b = html_entity_decode($a);
echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now
echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you fully. But just my point is you can save any data from form with processing via htmlspecialchars() and after you can fetch data from database with processing via html_entity_decode(). So if user would entered emplicit " he would got ", if he would entered &quot; he would got also &quot;If you worry about potentional XSS so here is not silver bullet, and you need just escape all potentional dangerous data, when you generate html (just as variant).

Comment: If you don't want to see &quot; in input (and it will be due using htmlspecialchars() as variant you can use JavaScript to replace &quot; by " in client-side. Use something like that for it:

your_js_string.replace(/&quot;/g, '\"')